# Replace string with textcontrols and get values from it in angular4+

Tags: angular

I am tring to Replace string with textcontrol and want to get that value on click of any button on same form.

For, Example
I have  string like **"I am ##. And I will be ##"**.
than this **##** should replace with *textbox* in angular side.

and on click of **button** i want to get the **values** of this both textbox.

Here is the some code sample code

```
 HTML
  <form [formGroup]="myForm">

 <div [innerHTML]="content"></div>

    <button (click)="checkData()">Check</button>
  </form>


          ************************TS***************************


    this.myForm.addControl('newcontrol', new FormControl());
    var $inputBox = '<input type="text" [formControl]="newcontrol"  id="FirstName" name="FirstName" class="form-control" >';

    this.content=this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml("I am ##. And I will be ##".replace(/##/g,$inputBox));


    checkData(){
    let ans= this.answer;
    debugger
    console.log(this.myForm);
    }
```

Comment: provide code  what you have tried

Comment: Added some code @ArunKumarMN